# Scala Play framework futures

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have 3 methods: a, b, and c.
Method a has some logic and it calls method b.
Method b makes an api call returning Future[String].
If the returned value from method b is a certain value, method c is called.
Method c makes another api call returning another Future[String].

```
def a: String = Action { request =>
  val x = b("hello")
  x
}

def b(y: String): Future[String] = {
  val x = ws.url(url).post(y).map { response =>
    val value = response.body
    val z = if (response.body === "hi") response.body else c(response.body)
    z
  }
  x
}

def c(z: String): Future[String] = {
  val x = ws.url(url).post(z).map { response =>
    response.body
  }
  x
}
```

Something like the code above. Eventually I want to parse everything into a json object, but I'm having trouble getting the Futures as regular strings. I'm new to scala and would appreciate some input.

Comment: you return   b("hello").flatMap(e => Ok(e)) and change your Action to Action.async

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
  def a: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { _ =>
    b("hello").map(s => Ok(s))
  }

  def b(y: String): Future[String] = {
    ws.url(url).post(y).flatMap { response =>
      if (response.body == "hi") Future.successful(response.body) else c(response.body)
    }
  }

  def c(z: String): Future[String] = {
    ws.url(url).post(z).map { response =>
      response.body
    }
  }
```

A few things.

1) The type of your method `a` will be an `Action[AnyContent]`, since you are creating a Play `Action`. It's common to see people omit the type of action methods and let the compiler figure it out. Note if your action is more sophisticated (e.g. it reads a JSON request body) then its type might be `Action[something_else]` (e.g. `Action[JsValue]` if you're using Play Json).

2) Because `b` returns a future, you need to create the `Action` using `Action.async` which takes a function of type `Request => Future[Response]` (before you were calling `Action.apply` which takes a function of type `Request => Response`).

3) In `A`, you need to `map` the `String` in the `Future` to a `Response`; I do this using `Ok` (i.e. HTTP 200), although of course you can use whatever's appropriate.

4) In `b`, `flatMap` is your friend, because `c` returns a `Future[String]` and thus you end up with a `Future[Future[String]]` when you use `map`... `flatMap` flattens that to a `Future[String]`.

5) You need to wrap the first branch of your `if` statement in `Future.successful`, such that both branches return the same type, `Future[String]`. `Future.successful` just builds a `Future` that is already completed.

6) Finally, you don't need to declare values `x`, `y` and `z`; each expression resolves to its value, which really tidies things up.